# How to change record value after 5 minutes

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

can i know where can i read on how to change a db value after a certain period of time like about 5 minutes? using Laravel php.. for example the value is '0' at first then after 5minutes it changes to "1". The reason is because each employee is having a different id.. so first employee is 0, second is 1, third is 2 and so on.. so a query will be passed to the first employee and after 5 minute if he didnt do anything with it then it will pass on to second employee.

Comment: Talk about the reason of this function

Comment: If you are on LINUX there is an option called Cronjob. It can do what you ask forr.

Comment: It'll not be the best way if he wants execute or change state frequently !

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can delay the dispatching of a job on a queue using delayed dispatching.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#delayed-dispatching

It works this way :

```
SendToNextEmployeeJob::dispatch($query)->delay(now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Where SendToNextEmployeeJob is a Job. You can generate it using :

```
php artisan make:job SendToNextEmployeeJob
```

you could create a Job to change your value, and dispatch it with a delay of five minutes.

Comment: im not sure about this, because i dont want to delay it, i just want to change to the next id(employee) after 5 mins if the first employee dont take an action

Comment: Yep : you create your Query, you push the job on the Queue with a delay of 5 minutes. When the Job is fired (so, after 5 minutes), you check if the first employee has done what you expect him to do, or else you send the Query to the next employee and push the job back on the queue (so it cycles every 5 minutes).